# NameError: name 'top' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror

I am trying to use Tkinter to create a GUI, the code is:

```
from tkinter import * 

class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    # initialize the login screen UI  
    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Login Screen")

        # create a menu bar
        menubar = Menu(top)

        # create a help menu
        helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="About", command=about)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

        # display the menu
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def about():
    """about info"""
    print("This is a Tkinter demo")


# create a button 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def make_button(parent, command, caption=NONE, side=top, width=0, **options): # name error 'top' is not defined
    """make a button"""
    btn = Button(parent, text=caption, command=command)

    if side != top:
        btn.pack(side=side)
    else:
        btn.pack()    

    return btn
def main():
    top = Tk()

    # Set up login frame properties 
    top.title("Login Screen")

    # create a login button
    login_btn = make_button(top, about, "Login")

    top.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried to run the code, python gave me the following error:

```
builtins.NameError: name 'top' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only define `top` in `main`, not at global scope, and even if it was at global scope, you defined it after `make_button`; default arguments in Python are evaluated once, at definition time, not looked up at call time.

The best approach would probably be to make most of your functions into class methods, and have the class itself create a `top` attribute.

But for the time being, you could do a minimalist change:

```
# Use None as a default at definition time, since top doesn't exist yet
def make_button(parent, command, caption=NONE, side=None, width=0, **options):
    """make a button"""
    if side is None:  # Convert None to top at call time
        side = top
    btn = Button(parent, text=caption, command=command)

    if side is not top:  # Minor tweak: Use identity test over equality
        btn.pack(side=side)
    else:
        btn.pack()    

    return btn

def main():
    global top  # Make top a global then define it
    top = Tk()

    ... rest of main ...
```

Note that this is still not great code; without `main` being executed, there is no `top` global defined, so your code is only usable as the main program, not as an importable module without a lot of hackery.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to top in the `make_button` parameter list - where you say `side=top`, but haven't actually defined `top` before that function. There is no global called top.

You can't set it as the default for a parameter until it is defined.

Comment: but, top is defined in tkinter and I have imported tkinter

Comment: @daiyue: Is it? In a Python 3.5 terminal, I just did `>>> import tkinter`, `>>> tkinter.top` and it gave an `AttributeError`.

Comment: I don't think it is in my distro - try typing from `tkinter import top` into your interpreter, and I think it will fail. You are defining top in your main function, but it is in local scope there - i.e. it can only be used withing the function.

Answer (score 0):

I also got same error, but I realized, I need to use upper case for "TOP" not "Top", after I used uppercase, it worked for me.

```
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()


root.title("Calcu_Displayframe")

num_1=StringVar()

topframe = Frame(root)
topframe.pack(side=TOP)

txtDisplay=Entry(frame, textvariable=num_1, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=30)
txtDisplay.pack(side=TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you import tkinter like this : import tkinter as tk
then the pack gonna be test.pack(tk.TOP)

if you import tkinter like this : from tkinter import *
then the gonna be test.pack(TOP)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).